# The name 'SongNameLabel' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

im begginer in C# and I've got a problem.

I'm getting error here:

```
songDetail = new SongDetailBind(MP3File.songName, "");
            SongNameLabel.DataContext = songDetail;
```

I'm writing it here: public partial class ControlPanel : UserControl
but SongNameLabel is label made in BottomPanel.xaml and and class of it is public partial class BottomPanel : UserControl.

How can I get access to SongNameLabel in ControlPanel class?

Comment: You are going to need to post more code then that...

Answer (score 0):

You can make a property or method in BottomPanel class to make this label avaliable in ControlPanel class.

```
public Label SongNameLabelProp
{
    get
    {
        return SongNameLabel;
    }
}
```

And then in ControlPanel if you have access to BottomPanel you can get do:

```
BottomPanel.SongNameLabelProp.DataContext = songDetail;
```

But generally making internal controlls accessible by other classes in a bad idea. You should be using some structural design pattern like MVVM and populate your views with data by data binding. Or at least make a method in BootomPanel class like:

```
public void SetSongDetail(SongDetailBind songDetail)
{
    SongNameLabel.DataContext = songDetail;
}
```